# Why order of dimension makes big difference in performance?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

To launch a CUDA kernel, we use `dim3` to specify the dimensions, and I think the meaning of each dimension is opt to the user, for example, it could mean (width, height) or (rows, cols), which has the meaning reversed.

So I did an experiment with the CUDA sample in the SDK: 3_Imaging/convolutionSeparable, simply exchage .x and .y in the kernel function, and reverse the dimensions of blocks and threads used to launch the kernel, so the meaning changes from dim(width, height)/idx(x, y) to dim(rows, cols)/idx(row, col).

The result is the same, however, the performance decreases, the original one takes about 26ms, while the modified one takes about 40ms on my machine(SM 3.0).

My question is, what makes the difference? is (rows, cols) not feasible for CUDA?

P.S. I only modified convolutionRows, no convolutionColumns

**EDIT:** The change can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jamboree/c9cfd8e7725371c3cbdf/revisions).

Comment: What was your kernel launch configuration?

Comment: @kronos, they're transposed, e.g. dim3(a, b) becomes dim3(b, a).

Comment: I am not familiar with the code referenced, but generally speaking this kind of thread-block configuration transpose interacts with the memory subsystem, because multiple-dimensional thread blocks are mapped in a specific way to global thread index. Generally you want unit-steps in the x-dimension to correspond to unit steps in array elements for best performance. I would suggest using the profiler to check on shared and global memory events to gain insight into the two variants of your specific case.

Comment: @Jamboree, yes I get this from your question, but how are the actual numbers? For example: 32x8 will (commonly) result in a better memory access pattern than 8x32, because all threads in a warp will access global memory coalesced.

Comment: It would be very useful to provide your code before and after the change because as the question stands we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two potential consequences of your changes:

1. First, you are changing the **memory access pattern** to the main memory so the
   access is as not coalesced as in the original case.

   You should think about the GPU main memory in the same way as it was
   a "CPU" memory, i.e., prefetching, blocking, sequential accesses...
   techniques to applies in order to get performance.

   If you want to know more about this topic, it is mandatory to read
   this paper. [What every programmer should know about memory](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~os142/wiki.files/drepper-2007.pdf).
   You'll find an example a comparison between row and column major
   access to the elements of a matrix there.

   To get and idea on how important this is, think that most -if not
   all- GPU high performance codes perform a matrix transposition
   before any computation in order to achieve a more coalesced memory
   access, and still this additional step worths in terms on
   performance. (sparse matrix operations, for instance)
2. Second. This is more subtle, but in some scenarios it has a deep impact on the performance of a kernel; the launching configuration. It is not the same launching 20 blocks of 10 threads as launching 10 blocks of 20 threads. There is a big difference in the amount of **resources a thread needs** (shared memory, number of registers,...). The more resources a thread needs the less warps can be mapped on a single SM so the less occupancy... and the -most of the times- less performance.
   *This not applies to your question, since the number of blocks is equal to the number of threads.*

When programming for GPUs you must be aware of the **architecture** in order to understand how that changes will modify the performance. Of course, I am not familiar with the code so there will be others factors among these two.

Comment: Memory access pattern is the problem, point 2 is not an issue here since the configurations are the same in sizes.

Comment: You're completely right. I'll change the answer to specify that.